# Get microsecond in PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have dataframe:

```py
from datetime import datetime
data = [
    (1, datetime(2018, 7, 25, 17, 15, 6, 390000)),
    (2, datetime(2018, 7, 25, 11, 12, 49, 317000))
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'max_ts'])
# +---+-----------------------+
# |ID |max_ts                 |
# +---+-----------------------+
# |1  |2018-07-25 17:15:06.39 |
# |2  |2018-07-25 11:12:49.317|
# +---+-----------------------+
```

I would like to create a column `milliseconds`:

```
+---+-----------------------+------+
|ID |max_ts                 |ms    |
+---+-----------------------+------+
|1  |2018-07-25 17:15:06.39 |390000|
|2  |2018-07-25 11:12:49.317|317000|
+---+-----------------------+------+
```

In pandas I can do this with

```py
df_interfax['ms_created_at'] = df_interfax['max_ts'].dt.microsecond
```

But how can I do it in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('ms', F.expr("date_part('s', max_ts) % 1 * pow(10, 6)"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+-----------------------+--------+
# |ID |max_ts                 |ms      |
# +---+-----------------------+--------+
# |1  |2018-07-25 17:15:06.39 |390000.0|
# |2  |2018-07-25 11:12:49.317|317000.0|
# +---+-----------------------+--------+
```

Another option:

```py
df = df.withColumn('ms', F.expr("unix_micros(max_ts) - unix_micros(date_trunc('second', max_ts))"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+-----------------------+------+
# |ID |max_ts                 |ms    |
# +---+-----------------------+------+
# |1  |2018-07-25 17:15:06.39 |390000|
# |2  |2018-07-25 11:12:49.317|317000|
# +---+-----------------------+------+
```